# Use variables as keywords for functions with pre-defined keywords (Python)

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to create a simple function that allows a user to input basic information that will change the values of a datetime object, and I'd like to find a way to make it as clean as possible by using a variable as a keyword.  This can easily be done a different way, but I figured it'd be useful to know how to replace pre-set keywords.

The datetime object has a .replace() method that takes any time value as a keyword:

> datetime.replace([year[, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]]]]])

But I want to allow the user to specify how much of which kind of time (e.g., 2 days; 4 hours; 1 month).

I'm trying to replace any of the above keywords up to "minute" with whatever the user inputs, which is stored in the *time_type* variable, but I get "**TypeError: 'time_type' is an invalid keyword argument for this function**".

```
    start_time = datetime.datetime(2016, 09, 16, 15, 30)

    def change_time(integer, time_string):
        time_type = time_string.replace("s","")  # de-pluralizes input
        new_time = getattr(start_time, time_type) + integer
        print(start_time.replace(time_type=new_time))

    change_time(2, "days")
```

This should print the new start_time, which is (2016, 09, 18, 15, 30), but I just get an error.

Comment: Build a dictionary of keyword arguments, then use `**` to unpack it (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python allows you to store data in a dictionary and finally unpack them as keyword arguments to different functions.

For the thing that you want to do, best way to accomplish this is to use kwargs.

```
replacement_info = {'day': 2, 'month': 9, ...}

new_time = start_time.replace(**replacement_info)
```

Note the difference with what you've done. Passing `time_type` directly to `replace`, would result in `replace` being called with the `time_type` parameter, set to 2, which is undefined (since it's not in the list of accepted arguments for replace)

Instead you have to pass it like `**{time_type: 2}` to the replace function, this way, replace will receive the interpreted value for time_type, namely day, as the input.

So you need to change

```
print(start_time.replace(time_type=new_time))
```

to

```
print(start_time.replace(**{time_type:new_time})
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace keyword arguments on a function you did not write. When calling a function like:

```
f(a=b)
```

The value of `a` is not sent as an argument to `f`. Instead, the value of `b` is sent and that value is set to the argument `a` in `f's` argument list definition. If `f` does not have an argument `a` defined (as `datetime.replace` does not have a `time_type` argument defined), you will get an `invalid keyword argument` exception.

As others have said, to pass dynamic keyword arguments to a function use the `**kwargs` notation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line to something like this:

```
year = start_time.year
month = start_time.month
day = start_time.day
hour = start_time.hour
minute = start_time.minute
second = start_time.second
microsecond = start_time.microsecond
exec(time_type + '='+str(new_time))
print(start_time.replace(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond)
```